# localhost connection is refused in soap UI

Tags: soapui

After creating a mock web service in SOAPUI and then pointing the request to the local endpoint, it is giving me the SOAP response instantly.

However, when i close the SOAPUI and after starting it again, and then hitting the request to the same local endpoint, it is refusing the connection.i Dont know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you also restart the mock service?

Comment: I dont see the option for restarting the mock service, could you please let me know how to restart it?

Comment: The green arrow? http://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/getting-started.html

Comment: In SOAP-UI disable proxy settings at `Files->Preferences->Proxy Settings` by checking `none`